# Passed scopes to Twitch API being ignored by Auth0

Tags: vue.js, oauth, auth0, twitch, twitch-api

I have been trying to read twitch user subscription data using Auth0 - to no avail.

I found [some information](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/interfaces/auth0clientoptions.html#scope) in their documentation, explaining how to add customs scopes to the authentication request.

I am importing the createAuth0Client function from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js" and calling the below

```
 this.auth0Client = await createAuth0Client({
        domain: options.domain,
        client_id: options.clientId,
        audience: options.audience,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        scope: 'email profile user:read:subscriptions' // change the scopes that are applied to every authz request. **Note**: `openid` is always specified regardless of this setting
      });
```

When I am redirected to twitch to authenticate, it is only requesting access to my email. Read subscriptions is never requested, and thus is not authorized.

Any guidance or example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am already stuck on this problem.